# how do i run a .kv file in Vscode

Tags: python, kivy

it does not show a problem but i cant run the .kv file in vscode
the .py file with kivy imported doesnt run anymore after i made the .kv file

Some Important Details:
https://youtu.be/l8Imtec4ReQ
am learning it from this video where the guy used pycharm iDE

the name of both the files is thelab.py and thelab.kv
no gaps all smallcase

kivy extension by battlebas has been installed
#:kivy ! is defined in .kv file

Will attach the error with running .py file

How do i fix it and run the .kv file as the guy in the video
should i just install pycharm

tried to run .kv file and it cant run [The terminal error when i run .py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccsTz.png)